# How is it possible to have changes in a database available at a later stage inside a local transaction?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a vb.net application that updates a record in table A and then inserts a record in the same table, inside a local transaction (in SQL Server 2005.)

```
_DbConnection.Open()
Try
    _Transaction = _DbConnection.BeginTransaction()

    If _DbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        bProcessSuccessfully = Update()

        _Transaction.Commit()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Try
        _Transaction.Rollback()
    Catch ex2 As Exception
        Logger.Error(ex2.Message)
    End Try
Finally
    _DbConnection.Close()
End Try
```

The `Update` method updates a field (lets call it `ID`) which has a unique constraint and sets it to a new *unique* value. Then it proceeds to insert a new record in the table using the old value of field `ID`.

For example if field `ID` has the value `0542-70-00002`, the existing record is updated with `ID=0542-70-00002/S` and a new record is inserted with `ID=0542-70-00002`.

The problem is that when trying to insert the new record I get an exception `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UF_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'A'`.

The code above does not fail all the time. In fact until today was not failing at all. I made sure (using git's log) that no changes were made to this code that could cause this change in its behavior.

So the question is, what needs to be done to make the updated value of field `ID` visible when the insertion is performed in order to succeed? Both the update and the insertion need to be performed inside a transaction, since I need an all-or-nothing operation.

I have tried specifying a different isolation level in `BeginTransaction` (`ReadCommited` and `ReadUncommited`), but the problem persists.

The `Update` method is as follows:

```
    If _DbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Dim sMarkAsObsolete As String = "UPDATE A" + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "SET ID = @ProductStructureCode" + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "WHERE AA = @ProductStructureRowID"

        Using sqlMarkAsObsolete As New SqlCommand(sMarkAsObsolete, _DbConnection)
            sqlMarkAsObsolete.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sqlMarkAsObsolete.Transaction = _Transaction

            Dim iMaterialID As Integer = ProductIdToMaterialRowID(_ProductStructure.ProductID)

            Dim aMaterial As Material_LD = New Material_LD(iMaterialID)

            sqlMarkAsObsolete.Parameters.Add("@ProductStructureCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = String.Format("{0}/Σ{1}", aMaterial.Code, CountAlternativeTechnicalSpecifications)
            sqlMarkAsObsolete.Parameters.Add("@ProductStructureRowID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BasicTechnicalSpecificationID

            bSuccessfullyMarkedAsObsolete = sqlMarkAsObsolete.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0
        End Using
    End If

    Dim sInsertProductStructureHeader As String = "INSERT INTO clroot.PRBPlan" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                  "  (ID, Description, MaterialAA, StartDT, EndDT, Text1, Text2, Text4, Quantity, BasQty, IsValid, IsBasic, IsProd, IsMRP, RecCrU)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                  "VALUES" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                  "  (@ProductStructureCode, @Description, @ProductID, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo, @UserDimensions, @ProductStructureType, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, @CreatedBy)"

    Using sqlInsertProductStructureHeader As New SqlCommand(sInsertProductStructureHeader, _DbConnection)
        sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Transaction = _Transaction

        Dim iMaterialID As Integer = ProductIdToMaterialRowID(_ProductStructure.ProductID)

        Dim aMaterial As Material_LD = New Material_LD(iMaterialID)

        If aMaterial.HasBeenAssignedFinalCode Then
            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@ProductStructureCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aMaterial.Code
            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aMaterial.Description
            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iMaterialID

            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@ValidFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = New Date(1980, 1, 1)
            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@ValidTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = New DateTime(2030, 12, 31, 23, 59, 0)

            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@UserDimensions", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserSpecifiedDimensions
            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@ProductStructureType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _ProductStructure.StructureType

            sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sCreatedBy

            bHeaderInsertionIsSuccessful = sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1

            If bHeaderInsertionIsSuccessful Then
                ' This works because field AA is marked as Identity
                sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.CommandText = sGetRowIdentity

                _RowID = sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.ExecuteScalar()
            End If
        End If
    End Using
```

The exception is raised in this line:

```
bHeaderInsertionIsSuccessful = sqlInsertProductStructureHeader.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1
```

I think it gives an idea about what is happening in the code.

Comment: Show us the code of your `Update()` method

Comment: It seems that your `clroot.PRBPlan` table has a primary key at  `ID` column and you're trying to INSERT a new record with an ID (`aMaterial.Code`) which already exists. Did you check that?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure that the new value been assigned to the `ID` column is unique. It is the first thing I checked and did so multiple times. That is the role of the update operation, it changes the field's value to a new unique value before attempting to insert a new row.

Comment: If the value of the `ID` field is GGG for example, the update will make it GGG/S and a new record will be inserted with `ID=GGG`.

Comment: I'm almost sure that this is your problem and your update of `aMaterial.Code` to make it unique is not working fine. Try to remove the primary key of the `clroot.PRBPlan` and check if the ID is repeated after some insertions.

Comment: Another work around could be set your transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE which places a range lock on the data set, preventing other users from updating or inserting rows into the data set until the transaction is complete. Because concurrency is lower, use this option only when necessary.

Comment: Although sure that the value assigned to field `ID` when the row is updated is unique, I assigned a hard coded unique value just to check your hypothesis (which was also my hypothesis at the beginning!) The problem persists. It is as if the update is not visible to the insertion. I also tried your suggestion about using `IsolationLevel.Serializable`, but it made no difference.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't pay much attention to your error message. Since it specifies `Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'A'`, the problem seems to be that you are trying to update `A` with a code which already exits in `A`, not in `clroot.PRBPlan` table. So your problem resides at your UPDATE statement, not at your INSERT statement.

Comment: No, I should be sorry. The problem is that at the beginning I did not paste the table's name (`clroot.PRBPlan`), just a placeholder (A).